# Referencing nuget packages from nuget package

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I have a nuget package which depends on several other ones (e.g. `Newtonsoft.Json`).
Package is not intended to use as a class library it only adds custom MSBuild action so the structure of the package looks like that:

```
-package CustomBuildAction
|-lib/net45/CustomBuildAction.dll
|-build/CustomBuildAction.targets
```

When I install the package `CustomBuildAction.targets` is correctly referensed from csproj but when I'm trying to run build I get an error that:

The "CustomBuildAction" task couldn't be loaded from assembly "path to dll/CustomBuildAction.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll, Version=...' or one of its dependencies.

I have included `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` into nuspec file as a package dependency, nuget shows it as a dependency but MSBuild is unable to resolve it. For me it looks like the problem is that I'm referencing `CustomBuildAction.dll` from .targets file using relative path (relative to build folder) in packages folder, i.e.:

```
../lib/net45/CustomBuildAction.dll
```

But this dll isn't intended to be placed into the build output folder where it could find all its dependencies.
How can I resolve this issue? Should I include dependencies right into the package or there is another way to solve it?

Comment: Does the project need to reference the CustomBuildAction.dll if it is only used by the custom MSBuild action? I would just have it in the build directory next to the .targets file and then import it from there. Then have the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the build directory too.

Comment: @Matt Ward no, there's no need to add it as a reference into project. Will try to move dll into build folder, interesting idea

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild will resolve task dependencies from the folder containing the task assembly. Unfortunately, this means you need to include Newtonsoft.Json.dll in your NuGet package along side your CustomBuildAction.dll file.

To prevent the assemblies from ending up in build output, put the assemblies into a different folder in the package. For examples, tools/  as long as it's not in lib, it won't be treated as an assembly that is available to reference.